# Best Practice: creating a nested associative array JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, whatsapp

It's been a while I have been on here and I hope I still understand the rules.
I have recently started learning PHP and WordPress for a Whatsapp Chatbot integration.
I have created a webhook on my WordPress site that returns a JSON, which is consumed by Google Dialogflow(Chatbot engine).

For example, my webhook returns something like this

```
{
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "Text response from webhook"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To achieve this structure, I have written used this nested associative array

```
$innerarr= array();
$innerarr[0] = "Text response from webhook";
$newarr = array();
$newarr["fulfillmentMessages"]= array();
$newarr["fulfillmentMessages"][0] = array("text"=>array("text"=>$innerarr));
echo json_encode($newarr);
```

It works but I'm also thinking, should I

1. Use a class definition instead that manages the above?
2. Use the \stdClass object to dynamically create this structure?
3. Is there a neater way to do this as the dynamic properties will grow depending on the request from the chatbot
4. Am I overthinking?

Comment: This question may be closed for asking for "general best practices".

Answer (score 2):

Your vague sample indicates that you are only pushing one text message into the structure.

- I see no compelling reason to declare the variables in your sample script.
- There is also no benefit in creating objects, because `json_encode()` is going to be using the same syntax when the data is converted to a json string.

I recommend that you do away with the single-use variables and write the necessary structure directly into the `json_encode()` call.

Code: ([Demo with `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` for readabilty](https://3v4l.org/ZOBNI))

```
echo json_encode(
         [
             'fulfillmentMessages' => [
                 [
                     'text' => [
                         'text' => [
                             'Text response from webhook',
                         ]
                     ]
                 ]
             ]
         ]
     );
```

I am unable to advise on "*the dynamic properties will grow depending on the request from the chatbot*" because you have not been clear about what this data will look like.  Asking for "General Best Practices" is off-topic on CodeReview.

Comment: Just for completeness, No difference if using assoc arrays or objects. Well there is one exception - empty array vs. empty object. One is encoded as array and the other as object. Unless JSON_FORCE_OBJECT is used....

Answer (score 0):

Do you can use a converter tool to help you understand the conversion structure, ex.: [wtools.io](https://wtools.io/convert-json-to-php-array).
In this case, the PHP array structure for your json is similar that it:

```
$innerarr = array (
  'fulfillmentMessages' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'text' => 
      array (
        'text' => 
        array (
          0 => 'Text response from webhook',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

echo json_encode($innerarr);
```

or, using sort arrays:

```
$innerarr = [
  'fulfillmentMessages' => [
    0 => [
      'text' => [
        'text' => [
          0 => 'Text response from webhook',
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ],
];

echo json_encode($innerarr);
```

Comment: You have provided two alternative approaches, but I am not sure that you have provided a _review_.  Why is `$innerarr` a good variable name for the entire set of data?